# Hours of labor required for 2007 Altima 2.5 engine refresh/rebuild

Tags: engine, nissan, altima

The cost obviously depends on the mechanic's hourly rate, but I know that the manufacturers provide authorized dealers with a guide of how many hours each service / job should take.

However I can't seem to find this info for the Altima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly it would be cheaper to buy a new engine rather than rebuild.

Your looking at roughly 26.6 hours. This is just labor, this does not include new seals, bearings, gaskets etc...

R&R on an engine is 11.6 hours.

Comment: right, a low-milage non-hybrid engine is < $1000. Whats reasonable hrs of labour for engine swap?

Comment: 11.6 hours to remove and replace the engine. This isn't including fluids or system bleeding so add another hour or so onto that.